# Ubuntu - performance - graphics drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I have a Intel J1800 (integrated graphic card) with Ubuntu 16.04 installed.
The problem is performance f.e while playing full HD movies (f.e. on yt).

I know the processor is able to play such movies - when windows was installed, there were **no such problems.**. So I believe, that it is driver issue.

Currently installed driver is `Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs for intel-microcode (proprietary)`.
What driver should I consider? How to find the cause of performance issue?

Comment: On YouTube, are you you using [the HTML5 player](https://www.youtube.com/html5) ?

Comment: Both - HTML & Flash - the same issue.

Comment: There is no Intel standalone driver. It looks like there is nothing that can improve perfomance with this adapter.